# validate date using java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate date like `24-mar-2014` with java regular expression.  but not able get correct regular expression.

Can someone please correct it.

```
\\d{2}-[a-z]-\\d{4}
```

Comment: In case a regex is not mandatory, have a look at `SimpleDateFormat` .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$
```

Comment: Please use a case-insenstive modfier - as it  won't match OPs example as it is. And didn't java need double backslashes, like `\\d`

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Yes, but if you try to validate a data with RegEx, and not allow stuff like `31st Feb`, or `29th` not on a leap year, it would be so long it would be completely impractical

Comment: The answer is incomplete then.

Comment: @Druzion *"it would be so long it would be completely impractical"* That is why validating a date with a regex is a bad idea.